# Accanthis font simple usage

Tags: fonts

I am using the Latex Font catalog:

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

I can set some of the fonts, however I cannot set a lot that I want. For example, I can set "Carolmin" effectively in a document. (See below example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{carolmin}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\cminfamily

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

\end{document}
```

However, I cannot get "Accanthis" to work, which is the font I really want to use. This is frustrating especially since the "example" file provided on the font catalog website does not compile after a bit of effort.

Here is my (non-working) accanthis.tex example. I have an accanthis.sty file in the same directory. I downloaded the accanthis.sty file by typing the filename into Google, then deleting the html tags on the document that came up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accanthis}

\begin{document}

{\accanthis Hello there!}

\end{document}
```

I hope you can provide some feedback here!

Comment: That "accanthis" document should work assuming your TeX installation is up to date.  On my system (TeX Live 2013), your document works just fine -- with or without the `\accanthis` -- but it is using `accanthis.sty` and `T1AccanthisADFStdNoThree.fd`, both from 2013/11/04.  (You can check this by adding `\listfiles` to your `.tex` file, recompiling, and then looking at the end of the `.log`.)  In other words, you need both the `.sty` file and various font-files related to `accanthis` installed.  (Exactly which font files depends on whether you use pdfTeX, LuaTeX, or XeTeX to compile...)

Comment: ok, so I am using pdfLaTex to compile. I have typed \listfiles and at the end of the log, all I see is the fatal error.

Comment: Indeed.  That sounds like you don't actually have the fonts installed.  MiKTeX includes a package installer, I believe, so I would try to use that rather than doing the installation of all files by hand...

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no problem with your latex code. The accanthis is displayed in my compiled page (pdf page).

You can check with this source,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accanthis}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \sfdefault

    \ttdefault

    \rmdefault

    {\accanthis \lipsum[1] 1234567890}

    {\rm \lipsum[1] 1234567890}

    {\tt \lipsum[1] 1234567890}

    {\sf \lipsum[1] 1234567890}

\end{document}
```

## Edited

I've modified the code to compare with accanthis style in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/accanthis/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accanthis}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

    \doublespacing
    \Large

    \sfdefault

    \ttdefault

    \rmdefault

    {\rm The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

    {\accanthis The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}    

    {\itshape The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

    {\bfseries The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

    {\bfseries\itshape The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

    {\tt The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

    {\sf The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

This is the result
[image: running code]

compare with
[image: from www.tug.dk]

Comment: I have installed accanthis using miktex, but now I have a "fatal error": The AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular-lf-t1--base source file could not be found

Comment: @TeXUser -- that error indicates that you don't have the necessary font files installed.  For fonts to work, you need the fonts *and* a way to use them in a *TeX document.  `accanthis.sty` just provides a convenient wrapper so you can use the font (if installed) with minimal hassle.

Comment: @jon please direct me to the font files... I installed the accanthis with miktex and I downloaded an accanthis.sty file.

Comment: @TeXUser -- I always look to [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/accanthis) first, which, in this case, seems to include everything you need.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how things are done on MiKTeX ... but I note that the package is said to be included in MiKTeX, which I would think means everything would already be installed..?

Comment: @TexUser, if you use `TeXstudio`, the apps will prompt to download the missing packages from ctan site when you type package name, in this case `\usepackage{accanthis}`.

Comment: maybe this link will help, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows, and for the package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/accanthis/

Answer (score 0):

TWhat happened is most likely that you do have the fonts installed in the TeXMF directory. You can check that looking for  `accanthis` directorie in the `MiKTeX 2.9` directory. It happens from time to time that MiKTeX package manager forgets to update the type 1 fonts data base.

So run `updmap --verbose` from the command line. You can check the Accanthis font are mentioned in `psfonts.map`, that you'll find in `C:\Users\Your_name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config`.